# How to know if the iOS camera is not focused and not adjusting

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, avcapturesession

We're making an app where we need to show one of the following states:

- focused,
- focusing (adjusting),
- not focused.

It seems that when you move the camera around, the camera will not try to adjust until you stop the movement. So how to identify this state?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the adjustingFocus property of AVCaptureDevice to accomplish what you mentioned. More information on the same can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/adjustingFocus) .

Comment: Hi, as I was trying to say, it will not start adjusting the focus until you hold the phone still. While I'm moving the phone around it appears that the camera is not correctly focused nor is it trying to to adjust focus... so I want to know how to check if it's in this state..

Comment: One of the first steps in this problem would be to determine the current AVCaptureFocus mode [ http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/focusMode ] . Subsequently, you would also have to get accelerometer readings to determine if the camera is moving.

Comment: Ok, it's not so much about the moving itself. In case that wasn't clear. It's about the fact that the camera is not trying to adjust focus... The camera neither is focused or trying to get focused...